# Path Integral for Unruh Effect

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, qft-in-curved-spacetime, wick-rotation, unruh-effect

In derivation of Unruh effect, according to [arxiv 2108.09188](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.09188), we have
$$
\langle\phi_L|\exp(-\pi H)|\phi_R\rangle=\int_{\phi=\phi_R}^{\phi=\phi_L} D\phi e^{-S_E}\propto \int_{lower\space half\space plane}^{\phi_L\space,\space\phi_R} D\phi e^{-S_E}=\langle\phi_L\space\phi_R|0\rangle.\tag{1.13}
$$
I do not understand why.

[image]

This is the figure in the article. Fig. 2a) is $<\phi_L|\exp(-\pi H)|\phi_R>$ and 2b) is $<\phi_L\space\phi_R|0>$.
How can this figure prove that they are proportional?

Edit:
I know intuitivly that both the integral sum up the whole spaces. However, when I explicitly write out the two terms,
$$
\langle\phi_L|\exp(-\pi H)|\phi_R\rangle=\int d\phi_1\int d\phi_2...\int d\phi_n\langle\phi_L|exp(-\delta\theta H)|\phi_n\rangle\langle\phi_n|...|\phi_1\rangle\langle\phi_1|exp(-\delta\theta H)|\phi_R\rangle
$$
and
$$
\langle\phi_L\space\phi_R|0\rangle=\int d\phi_1...\int d\phi_n\langle\phi_L\space\phi_R|exp(-\delta tH)|\phi_{L,n}\phi_{R,n}\rangle...\langle\phi_{L,1}\phi_{R,1}|exp(-\delta tH)|0\rangle
$$
How can we calculate that they are proportional to each other mathematically? (I feel that these diagrams represent mathematically expression instead of being real space)

P.S.
Another thing that I notice is that on the left of (1.13) we write $\langle\phi_L|\exp(-\pi H)|\phi_R\rangle$ while on the right we write $\langle\phi_L\space\phi_R|0\rangle$ instead of $\langle\phi_L\space\phi_R|exp(-tH)|0\rangle$. Is $\langle\phi_1|exp(-tH)|\phi_2\rangle=\langle\phi_1|\phi_2\rangle$ in general? What about the Lorentzian amplitude $\langle\phi_1|exp(-itH)|\phi_2\rangle$ and $\langle\phi_1|\phi_2\rangle$?

Answer (score 2):

Briefly speaking, boosts become rotations in the Euclidean formulation, and  it is possible to re-slice the thermal state by appropriate coordinate transformations. This is discussed in much more detail by Tom Hartman in the [4th lecture from the fall of 2021](http://www.hartmanhep.net/topics2021/) using nice pictures (starting at [20:00 in the YouTube video](https://youtu.be/o1EW9wUn21U?t=1200) and page 5 in the [PDF file](http://www.hartmanhep.net/topics2021/lecturenotes/4-Unruh%20Radiation.pdf)).

Comment: Hi Qmechanic, perhaps this is worth its own question (if it hasn't been asked before), but how should one carefully argue that slicing the Euclidean path integral in this way corresponds to evolution by the rotation operator? It's certainly an intuitive picture, but I must admit I don't even totally know what it means.